# What is the cheapest way to sort a permutation in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, combinations

**The problem is:**

You have to sort an array in ascending order(permutation: numbers from 1 to N in a random order) using series of swaps. Every swap has a price and there are 5 types of prices. Write a program that sorts the given array for the smallest price.
There are two kinds of prices: **priceByValue and priceByIndex**. All of the prices of a kind are given in 2 two-dimensional arrays N*N. Example how to access prices:
You want to swap the 2nd and the 5th elements from the permutation with values of 4 and 7. The **price for this swap will be priceByValue[4][7] + priceByIndex[2][5]**.

Indexes of all arrays are counted from 1 (, not from 0) in order to have access to all of the prices (the permutation elements’ values start from 1): priceByIndex[2][5] would actually be priceByIndex[1][4] in code. Moreover, the order of the indexes by which you access prices from the two-dimensional arrays doesn’t matter: priceByIndex[i][j] = priceByIndex[j][i] and priceByIndex[i][i] is always equal to 0. (priceByValue is the same)

**Types of prices**:

1. Price[i][j] = 0;
2. Price[i][j] = random number between 1 and 4*N;
3. Price[i][j] = |i-j|*6;
4. Price[i][j] = sqrt(|i-j|) *sqrt(N)*15/4;
5. Price[i][j] = max(i,j)*3;

When you access prices by index i and j are the indexes of the elements you want to swap from the original array; when you access prices by value i and j are the values of the elements you want to swap from the original array. (And they are always counted from 1)

**Things given:**
**N - an integer from 1 to 400**, Mixed array, Type of priceByIndex, priceByIndex matrix, Type of priceByValue, priceByValue matrix. (all elements of a matrix are from the given type)

**Things that should 'appear on the screen':** number of swaps, all swaps (only by index - 2 5 means that you have swapped 2nd and 3rd elements) and the price.

As I am still learning C++, I was wondering what is the most effective way to sort the array in order to try to find the sort with the smallest cost.
There might be a way how to access series of swaps that result a sorted array and see which one is with the smallest price and I need to sort the array by swapping the elements which are close by both value and index, but I don’t know how to do this. I would be very grateful if someone can give me a solution how to find the cheapest sort **in code**. Thank you in advance!

More: **this problem might have no solution**, I am just trying to get a result close to the ideal.

Comment: "all elements of a matrix are random from the given type"; what does that mean? Are there 25 instances of the problem, each with a set "price type" for each matrix? Are there 5, each with a set type for both matrices? Or are each entry in the matrices of a random type?

Comment: Show what you've tried. I'm sure you can solve the problem where all prices are 1 (meaning, solve the problem with the fewest swaps) and I doubt anyone is willing to solve the whole thing like that.

Comment: There are two two-dimensional arrays with prices and both arrays have a type (from 0 to 4) and all elements of an array are from the given type. (I didn't mean random, sorry. I would edit it.)

Comment: I also added some info about N and I am sorry I didn't mention that the sorting should be in ascending order. The problem is very long. Also, if someone has questions don't hesitate to ask me.

Comment: I would also like to say that I would be very grateful if I get more than one suggestion in order for me to be able to deal with it effectively. Thanks!

Comment: Have you implemented a brute-force search algorithm?

Comment: #BgGoranoff Could you please show us the code you wrote so far? And where does this problem come from? could you please link the source?

Comment: Since a price cannot be negative, there definitely is a solution: there are only a finite number of possible sequences of swaps without repetition that sort the array, and each has a total price, you just have to find the sequence with the smallest price. The question is, do you want an *efficient* approximation, or an *effective* solution? Btw, "cost" is probably more appropriate than "price" in this context.

Comment: @Nelfeal, I agree that cost is more appropriate here, thank you. Also, I agree that there are only a finite number of series of swaps that result a sorted array, but I really don't know how count them so I can find the one with smallest price. I would be grateful if someone can suggest me a way to do this.

Comment: I know that Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service and I have been thinking on this problem for a couple of days, but I cannot find a solution how to count series of swaps that result a sorted array. I would be really pleased if I could find a good solution or suggestion on how to do this here.

Comment: As I've said before, solve the problem where all costs are constant, in other words solve the problem of efficiently sorting the array without taking costs into account. Once you've done that, you can post your solution here and we can help you tackle the problem of costs. To give you some pointers, a "swap" here is formally called a [transposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation#Transpositions), which is a special case of permutation. Permutations can be composed into other permutations, and for any array, there exists a single permutation that sorts it.

Comment: OK, I would send my work in a couple of hours. (Once I get to my computer)

Comment: This problem doeesn't appear to have a lot of educational value for someone who is learning C++ or programming. It looks like a bunch if randomly generated formulas thrown together in order to confuse the attacker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic Programming!

Think of the problem as a graph.  Each of the N-factorial permutations represents a graph vertex, and the allowed swaps are just arcs between vertices.  The price-tag of a swap is just the weight on the arc.

When you look at the problem this way, it can be easily solved with Dijkstra's algortihm for finding the lowest cost path through a graph from one vertex to another.

This is also called Single Pair Shortest Path

Comment: The only problem here is that there is `n!` vertices in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an algorithm for sorting an array in lexicographical order and modify it so that it fits your needs ( you did not mention the sorting criteria like the desired result i.e. least value first, ... ) there are multiple algorithms available for this, i.e. *quick sort,...*

a code example is in *https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lexicographic-permutations-of-string/*

Comment: **Thank you** for the quick answer @ralf htp. I would read this page and try to modify it so it fits my needs. Also, the permutation should be sorted in ascending order. Sorry about that I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Moreover, this problem might have no solution. I am just trying to find the most effective method that leads to a result, close to the ideal.